# css urls pointing to absolute path, noth relative

Tags: css, laravel, laravel-5.4

So, I have a fresh Laravel 5.4 project that has font-awesome-sass installed and it is installed in 
http://localhost/projects/laravel54 .

For some reason the font files are being searched in "http://localhost/fonts...." instead of "http://localhost/projects/laravel54/public/fonts..." . 
I am compiling my css with Laravel mix without any issues, but i don't understand why does the css file of fontawesome searches the files in the absolute path, not relative to where the file is... 
The compiled css for font-awesome looks like this

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url(/fonts/vendor/font-awesome-sass/font-awesome/fontawesome-webfont.eot?674f50d287a8c48dc19ba404d20fe713);
  src: url(/fonts/vendor/font-awesome-sass/font-awesome/fontawesome-webfont.eot?674f50d287a8c48dc19ba404d20fe713) format("embedded-opentype"), url(/fonts/vendor/font-awesome-sass/font-awesome/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?af7ae505a9eed503f8b8e6982036873e) format("woff2"), url(/fonts/vendor/font-awesome-sass/font-awesome/fontawesome-webfont.woff?fee66e712a8a08eef5805a46892932ad) format("woff"), url(/fonts/vendor/font-awesome-sass/font-awesome/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?b06871f281fee6b241d60582ae9369b9) format("truetype"), url(/fonts/vendor/font-awesome-sass/font-awesome/fontawesome-webfont.svg?912ec66d7572ff821749319396470bde) format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Has anyone had similar experience or plausible solution? Thanks!

Comment: `url(/fonts` means it will be relative to the root (in this case to localhost) and not relative to the project root. You will probably need to use a relative path like e.g. `url(fontawesome-webfont.eot)`

Answer (score 1):

Inserting this before any css compilation/concatination actions solved the issue.

```html
mix.options({
 processCssUrls: false
});
```